# matplotlib plot on cumulative graph from x-axis instead of y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated this cumulative chart using this code:

```
plt.hist(d.values(), normed=True, cumulative=True, label='CDF', histtype='step', alpha=0.8, color='r',
         orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

However i want something more like this where the graph starts from the x-axis:
[image]

How do i go about doing that?

Comment: `plt.ylim(ymin=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your second plot correctly, all you need to do is to get rid of `orientation='horizontal'` and `normed=True`

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab


mu = 200
sigma = 25
n_bins = 50
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, n_bins,
                            histtype='step', cumulative=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('cumulative step')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I want it normalized so i have to keep that. If i remove `orientation = 'horizontal'` the axis become swapped. i want the normalized axis to be the x-axis

Comment: Then isn't your first figure what you needed? I assume for your histogram with cumulative off, the x-axis is the number of nodes reached, y-axis is the number of nodes that reaches the number of nodes specified by the x-value. Is that not the case?

Comment: Take my Gaussian toy model for example, each number in the `x` vector represent a starting node, and the particular value is the number of nodes that starting node reaches.

Comment: yes, but why is there a line connecting back to the y-axis at the beginning and end? How do i remove that?

Comment: That's your bin size. You can make it smaller so that a bin looks like a line. Or you can get the histogram data from `counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(x)` and then plot it yourself.